# Set up default Decimal precision and scale for H2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have a project where Hibernate generates schema for H2 database:
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>`

For decimal columns by default it sets precision and scale `Decimal(19,2)`, but I need the scale to be 5, e.g. `Decimal(19, 5)`.
I can change it via annotation params:
`@Column(name = "amount", precision = 19, scale = 5)`

But is there a way to set the scale by default to 5 (in Hibernate/H2 configs) so there's no need to explicitly set the scale for every column?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, the default is encoded in `org.hibernate.mapping.Column`.

You could try to override it in general though if you really want by overriding `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#getTypeName(int, long, int, int)`.

Comment: I upvote your answer, but I won't accept it just in case there will be a Yes answer in future.